# How to find the force exerted by continuous jet of water on a wall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, momentum

[image]

Suppose, the water is flowing at a speed of $2m/s$. The cross-sectional area of the opening is $0.03m$, and the water is hitting the wall at right angles. Assuming the water doesn't rebound, how will I find the force exerted by the water on the wall?

**My attempt:**

The problem is that the water is flowing continuously from the pipe and hitting the wall. Also, water is a liquid thing. I know how to find the force of solid things, and when they are not flowing continuously. For example,

[image]

I know how to find the force in this case. Here, the ball is a solid thing, and it is not flowing continuously like the water: the ball will hit the wall only once unlike the gazillions of water molecules hitting the wall continuously. If the ball hits the wall straight at a speed of $2m/s$, if the mass of the ball is $1kg$, if the ball is in contact with the wall for $1s$, and if the ball doesn't rebound, then the force exerted by the wall on the ball will be

$$F=\frac{m(v-u)}{t}$$

$$F=\frac{1(0-2)}{1}$$

$$F=-2N$$

And the force exerted by the ball on the wall will be $+2N$.

**My question:**

1. How do I find the force exerted by the continuously flowing water on the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its solid or liquid the law doesnt change, so lets just apply Newtons second law again.

$$F=\frac{dP}{dt}=\dot{m}(v_f-v_i)$$

Where $\dot{m}$ is the amount of mass hitting the wall per unit time which would be $\rho A v$. As you said it doesnt rebound, the velocity along normal becomes 0. So $v_f-v_i=v \implies F=\rho A v^2$.

Now that you understood how to solve, if it doesnt rebound, try to solve it when it rebounds. Also, in the setup you showed, water falls down in a parabola so when it hits the wall some part of the velocity would be tangential to the wall, so try to solve that as well from newtons second law.